# Visual Studio 2015 MVC Scaffolding extremely slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have an issue - the scaffolding new controllers is extremely slow. When performing this action: Controllers --> "Add" --> "Controller..." --> "MVC 5 Controller with Views and Entity Framework" - the dialog box takes about 10 minutes to load. The generation step takes even longer - around 20 minutes.

I have tried disabling all of the visual studio add-ins.

This issue seems to affect just once solution which is fairly large (20 projects ~30 controllers). Creating a blank MVC project in a new solution and trying scaffolding works normally.

Any help would be appreciated. This issue is rather frustrating.

Comment: This might help? http://lennybacon.com/post/2010/10/18/UltimateGuideToSpeedUpVisualStudio

Comment: Do you have trouble in other projects? iIf the answer is yes Does your troubled hard disk drives or slowly run ? I suggest you can use SSD Hard Disk.

Comment: Instead of relying on some scaffolding auto-magic stuff did you try adding a plan C# class and just typing the code you need? Personally I have found that this approach is about a gazillion of magnitude faster and more efficient compared to relying on some black magic wizards writing the code for you.